# Foreach inside foreach inside foreach

Tags: c#

In my application I am using `scrape(string url)` method to scrape links from webpage. Lets say it is returning me 10 url's everytime.

I would like to scrape 10 links from every single one scraped url.

Long story short:

(step 1) go to the webpage and scrape 10 links

(step 2) foreach link from step 1 go to the webpage and scrape 10 links

(step 3) for each link from step 2 go to the webpage and scrape 10 links.

So it would give me 10 + 100 + 1000 links = 1110.

Of course I could do something like this:

```
    List<string> links1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> links2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> links3 = new List<string>();


    links1 = scrape("example.com"); //get 10 links

    foreach (string link in links1)
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        temp = scrape(link);
        links2.AddRange(temp);
    } //get 100 links

    foreach (string link in links2)
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        temp = scrape(link);
        links3.AddRange(temp);
    } // get 1000 links
```

But this is terrible to edit. What if I would like to scrape from scraped links 10 times? I would have to make 10 `foreach` loops.

Can you give me any advice?

Comment: You need a recursive function for do this, i think.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function would be your best bet.  However, you need to pass a parameter to keep track of "how deep" you are in your scrape or you might end up crawling the entire public web.

```
public List<string> GetLinks(List<string> urls, int depth){
    var newUrls = new List<string>();
    if(depth == 0) return newUrls ;
    foreach(var url in urls){
         newUrls.AddRange(scrape(url));
    }
    return urls.AddRange(GetLinks(newUrls, depth - 1);
}
```

Comment: It will work, but it would make sense, for this kind of task to write something that will allow parallel processing.

Comment: @Thomas -  Sure, there are ways to make this faster and better, but that wasn't the intent of the question :)  We just want to help OP get out of `foreach` hell!  Experimentally, `Parallel.Foreach()` may work, but its such a case by case basis, it didn't make sense to include.

Comment: I deleted `function` and it says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>"

Comment: @Dawvawd - Sorry about the cross language confusion.  Please declare this function as any other function in C#.  Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursion.

The idea here is to continue to invoke the same function until there are no children left. An example of recursion is inside of  a FindTreeNode in treelist function:

```
TreeListNode FindTreeNode(TreeListNode node, Enumerations.ItemType type, Nullable<long> id)
{
    foreach (var c in node.Nodes) 
    {
        if ((Enumerations.ItemType)c[2] == type &&
           (id == null || (long)c[0] == id.Value)) {

            return c;
        }

        if (c.HasChildren) 
        {
            // Here is the secret sauce
            // This is recursion
            var exists = FindTreeNode(c, type, id);
            if (exists != null) { return exists; }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Same idea as above, except in your case it's with web uri